How to split footer between odd and even pages?
The following python program generates pdf files with the same footer for all the pages.
However, when the footer is too long, it takes too much space. One way is to split the footer evenly between odd and even pages. How can I achieve this with reportlab?
import sys
sys.path.pop(0)
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont
from reportlab.pdfbase.pdfmetrics import registerFont, registerFontFamily

i =1; left_margin = int(sys.argv[i])
i+=1; rght_margin = int(sys.argv[i])
i+=1; top_margin = int(sys.argv[i])
i+=1; btm_margin = int(sys.argv[i])

i+=1; fontfam_name=sys.argv[i]
i+=1; fontconf_file=sys.argv[i]
with open(fontconf_file, 'r') as f:
    fontdict = {}
    for line in f:
        fname, ftype, fpath = line.rstrip('\n').split('\t')
        if fname == fontfam_name:
            if ftype == 'normal':
                fontdict[ftype] = f'{fname}'
            else:
                fontdict[ftype] = f'{fname}-{ftype}'
            registerFont(TTFont(fontdict[ftype], fpath))
    registerFontFamily(fontfam_name, **fontdict)

i+=1; main_fontsize = int(sys.argv[i])
i+=1; footer_fontsize = int(sys.argv[i])
i+=1; baselineskip = int(sys.argv[i])

from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet, ParagraphStyle
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
custom_style = ParagraphStyle(
        name='Custom'
        , parent=styles['Normal']
        , fontName='TimesNewRoman'
        , fontSize = main_fontsize
        , leading = main_fontsize + baselineskip
        , wordWrap='CJK'
        )

footer_style = ParagraphStyle(
        name='Custom'
        , parent=styles['Normal']
        , fontName='TimesNewRoman'
        , fontSize = footer_fontsize
        , leading = footer_fontsize + baselineskip
        , wordWrap='CJK'
        )

# styleN = getSampleStyleSheet()['Normal']

from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.units import mm

class PageNumCanvas(canvas.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        canvas.Canvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.pages = []

    def showPage(self):
        self.pages.append(dict(self.__dict__))
        self._startPage()

    def save(self):
        page_count = len(self.pages)
        for page in self.pages:
            self.__dict__.update(page)
            draw_footer(footer_lines, self.getPageNumber(), page_count, doc.leftMargin, doc.width, doc.bottomMargin, self)
            canvas.Canvas.showPage(self)
        canvas.Canvas.save(self)

from reportlab.platypus import BaseDocTemplate, Frame, PageTemplate, Paragraph, Spacer

i+=1; doc_id = sys.argv[i]
i+=1; footer_file = sys.argv[i]
if footer_file:
    with open(footer_file, 'r') as f:
        footer_lines = [line for line in f]
else:
    footer_lines = []

def footer_height(footer_lines, width, height):
    h0 = 0
    if doc_id:
        _, h = Paragraph('<para alignment="center">{doc_id} 1/1</para>', custom_style).wrap(width, height)
    else:
        _, h = Paragraph('<para alignment="center">1/1</para>', custom_style).wrap(width, height)
    h0 += h

    for line in footer_lines:
        if line == '\n':
            h0 += footer_fontsize + baselineskip
        else:
            _, h = Paragraph(line, footer_style).wrap(width, height)
            h0 += h

    return h0 + btm_margin
    #return h0 + footer_fontsize + baselineskip

def draw_footer(footer_lines, pg_num, tot_pg, left, width, height, c):
    h0 = height
    if doc_id:
        P = Paragraph(f'<para alignment="center">{doc_id} {pg_num}/{tot_pg}</para>', custom_style)
    else:
        P = Paragraph(f'<para alignment="center">{pg_num}/{tot_pg}</para>', custom_style)

    _, h = P.wrap(width, height)
    h0 -= h
    P.drawOn(c, left, h0)

    for line in footer_lines:
        if line == '\n':
            h0 -= footer_fontsize + baselineskip
        else:
            P = Paragraph(line, footer_style)
            w, h = P.wrap(width, height)
            h0 -= h
            P.drawOn(c, left, h0)

from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
width, height = letter

width -= left_margin + rght_margin
height -= top_margin + btm_margin
bottomMargin = footer_height(footer_lines, width, height)
if bottomMargin < btm_margin:
    bottomMargin = btm_margin

doc = BaseDocTemplate(sys.stdout.buffer
                                            , pagesize=letter
                                            , leftMargin = left_margin
                                            , rightMargin = rght_margin
                                            , bottomMargin = bottomMargin
                                            , topMargin = top_margin
                                            )

doc.addPageTemplates([PageTemplate(frames=Frame(doc.leftMargin, doc.bottomMargin, doc.width, doc.height))])
flowables = [Paragraph(line, custom_style) if line != '\n' else Spacer(1, main_fontsize+baselineskip) for line in sys.stdin]
doc.build(flowables, canvasmaker = PageNumCanvas)

$ cat ~/my.conf
TimesNewRoman   normal  /System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/Times New Roman.ttf
TimesNewRoman   bold    /System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/Times New Roman Bold.ttf
TimesNewRoman   italic  /System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/Times New Roman Italic.ttf
TimesNewRoman   boldItalic  /System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/Times New Roman Bold Italic.ttf

declare lmargin=24 rmargin=24 tmargin=36 bmargin=24
declare fontname=TimesNewRoman fontconf=~/my.conf mainfontsize=11 footerfontsize=9 baselineskip=1 docid
declare -a args=(
    "$lmargin" "$rmargin" "$tmargin" "$bmargin"
    "$fontname" "$fontconf"
    "$mainfontsize"
    "$footerfontsize"
    "$baselineskip" "$docid"
)
seq 200 | ../prog.py "${args[@]}" <(builtin printf '%s\n' {A..E}) > output.pdf

